# Does `provide` conflict with `use-package`?

Tags: use-package, provide

I just install `use-package` yesterday and still learning it. I notice `use-package` is not working in my environment:

Here is my init file:

```
(require 'package)
(dolist (url '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
               ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives url t))
(dolist (path '("~/.emacs.d/elpa" "~/.emacs.d/plugins/" "~/.emacs.d/lisp/"))
  (add-to-list 'load-path path))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))
(require 'init-treemacs)
```

Here is my `init-treemacs` file in `.emacs.d/lisp/`

```
(use-package treemacs-mode
  :ensure t
  :init (bind-key "C-x M-d" treemacs)
  :custom (treemacs-width 25))
(provide 'init-treemacs)
```

When I start Emacs, `treemacs` looks like not be loaded.

1. `C-x M-d` does not work
2. I start `treemacs` manually, and `treemacs-width` is not 25

Do I miss something? I have reinstalled `use-package`, compiled every file again, added & removed `ensure`. Nothing changed.

Emacs 26.1 installed by brewcask, `use-package` 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

treemacs-mode is not the name of the the package. It's just 'treemacs'

try

```
(use-package treemacs
 :ensure t
 :bind (("C-x M-d" . treemacs))
 :custom (treemacs-width 25)
 :config
  (provide 'init-treemacs))
```

I don't know if the provide statement needs to be within the config block, but this worked for me in testing.

- Chris

Comment: I am sorry about last commend Chris, it actually works, my mistake. Thanks for your help.